# Beauty Mode with CameraX

Tags: android, arcore, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I have been searching for beauty mode since last week and didn't find any resource except for some overpriced sdk. I want to know if there is any tool or resource which helps me to implement beauty mode in-camera preview like slim face, skin tone, eye size, etc.

what I found:

I found this Vendor extension - "BeautyImageCaptureExtender" but there is no official documentation in detail about this except enabling this on supported devices.

I know that we can detect face with Google ML Kit or we can use Android AR Core to apply image effects.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me with this.

[image]